# Subtracting two so close dates yields an apparent strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, behavior, difference

I was implementing a clock and a timer for my school assignment, and to implement the timer, I decided to create it by subtracting the dates between the start of the timer and the current date, but when I do it, I get always an hour more than the hours expected (0).

For example, using the console integrated in Chrome:

```
var d1 = new Date();
undefined

var d2 = new Date();
undefined

var diffDate = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
undefined

diffDate.getHours();
1
```

Of course I haven't waited for one hour to create `d2` after I created `d1`.

Why is this happening?

I have searched in some places, but none of them explains this behaviour. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: doesn't make sense creating a new date from the difference.....just do the math

Comment: @charlietfl Why shouldn't that make sense? `d.getTime()` should return the number of milliseconds since 1970 up to `d`.

Comment: Creating a new Date from the number of milliseconds between two dates doesn't really make sense. If you want to calculate the number of hours, you'll need to do something like `(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60)`.

Comment: @andersschuller Why it does not make sense? It makes a lot of sense. If Javascript is stupid and not well-implemented it is not my fault. By the way, the only thing that is wrong is the hours, one more than the expected one.

Comment: why would you use a date in 1970 as part of a calculation of 2 dates 45 years later than that?   Just do the math.

Comment: @Axl What do you expect to do with `diffDate`? Let's say the time between `d2` and `d1` is more than 24 hours. `diffDate.getHours()` will never return more than 23, because it will wrap to the next day (January 2nd, 1970).

Comment: @charlietfl Because theoretically getTime should return the number of milliseconds from 1970 from the two dates, and since the two dates are difference, I can subtract those numbers and create a new date. For me, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: well it's obviously not working...so just do the math

Comment: @charlietfl It's not because I don't want to do the math, I am not so stupid, Javascript is stupid, unless there's an explanation for this strange behaviour.

Comment: new Date returns a string. You cannot subtract them. You're looking for getTime(). edit: nevermind, I see where you're calling time.

Comment: @charlietfl So, can you explain me or not why do I receive one hour more than the expect 0?

Comment: no...I do understand what you are saying but can't explain it. Issue is probably searchable but I'm not really that interested

Comment: @charlietfl I simply do not understand why people keep using the most stupid language ever created.

Comment: @Radio and no it doesn't return a string...it returns a Date object

Comment: @Axl The issue is in your timezone. The dates must be showing in GMT+1 or GMT+1:30 timezone.

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I saw it. sry, would have deleted if allowed.

Comment: @JohnBupit That should not influence the result, since the two dates are from the same timezone, unless there are new ways of calculating hours and minutes, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

`getTime()` returns milliseconds since 1/1/1970. Calculating `d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()` will return the number of milliseconds between the two `new Date()` calls. (Probably zero if called one after the other).

`new Date(0)` will create a Date object for 0 milliseconds elapsed since 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC, but in your local timezone instead of UTC. `getHours()` simply returns the given hour in your local timezone setting for that point in time, which you said is "1". I would guess you are at GMT +1 (a bit east of England). It has nothing to do with time differences.

You really need to do some math with the millisecond difference, not create a new point in time with `new Date()`

Comment: What do you think about the approach suggested by John Bupit?

Comment: To be honest, this does not still make sense for me. Since both dates are from the same timezone, then the number of milliseconds between them should represent the correct distance anyway. Could you please clarify this point? In fact, if I get a date object now `d1`, and another after 10 seconds `d2`, then the number of milliseconds that separate the two dates should be 10000s anyway, thus `d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()` should yield simply `10000s`. By creating a date `d3` by simply passing `10000` to the constructor, we should have a correct date, no matter the timezone.

Comment: Maybe I am simply not understand how timezones are handle by these date objects...

Comment: A data structure that represents a point in time typically shouldn't be repurposed to store a time *duration*

Comment: @Axl You are correct that `d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()` would yield 10000 after 10 seconds pass. That's exactly the "time difference" you want. The next action of passing 10000 (ms) to the `new Date` constructor creates a Date object representing Jan.1st 1970 00:00:10 UTC. But JavaScript will automatically convert that point in time to your computer's local timezone. So you can't rely on `getHours()` because it will pull the hour represented in your local timezone.

Comment: @Axl What John Bupit said will give you the right time difference, because the UTC functions normalize to 1/1/70 00:00 UTC. You do have to be careful with functions like  `getUTCMinutes()` because it will roll over at 60 minutes to 0, and hour will increase by one. It would have to used together with `getUTCHours()` to be meaningful in these cases.

Comment: So, in this case you advise to also use getUTCMinutes and eventually getUTCSeconds along with getUTCHours?

Comment: @Axl Yes, to get the full picture you should get hours, minutes and seconds. Think of this procedure as pulling the plug off a desk alarm clock, plugging it back in when creating `d1`, (will auto-set the alarm clock to midnight), and reading the time on the clock when creating `d2`. Calling the UTC `get` functions is like reading this fictitious alarm clock.

Answer (score 2):

Your timezone is affecting your date. The default timezone in my browser is GMT+530 and here's the result I get:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
console.log(d1);
// Wed Sep 23 2015 00:54:08 GMT+0530 (IST)

var d2 = new Date();
console.log(d2);
// Wed Sep 23 2015 00:54:21 GMT+0530 (IST)


/*
 * Here, diffDate should be (and is!) Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+000.
 * In the local timezone of my browser, it becomes Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:13 GMT+0530 (IST)
 */
var diffDate = new Date(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime());
console.log(diffDate);
// Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:13 GMT+0530 (IST)

console.log(diffDate.getHours());
// 5

console.log(diffDate.getUTCHours());
// 0
```

[`getUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) bypasses the timezone, and returns the hours in UTC. `diffDate.getUTCHours()` should print `0`.

Comment: wow ...I get 19 in GMT-4 and in fact the last one is GMT-5, likely because daylight savings time changes in the fall